# Do you have to download a special version of Blender to use experimental features?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, experimental-features

I seem to be having problems enabling experimental features in Blender 2.78. I have tried using regular Blender and the experimental "developers only" version, but they both do the same thing. There is a warning icon with an exclamation mark next to the "Experimental" option in the Render panel, and the Displacement option does not appear in the Data panel. I want to enable true displacement for Cycles materials. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with an AMD 64-bit processor. I have not found any detailed instructions for enabling experimental features. The official documentation doesn't explain what the exclamation mark means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you don't need a special version of Blender. They come with Blender. You can enable them in various places in Blender.

For example, the experimental rendering features:

[image]

Another example - add-ons:

[image]

---

For your specific case, enable the experimental rendering features like you mentioned, then switch [displacement](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html#true-displacement) type in the material settings (this will work with something attached to the displacement input of the material output node).

[image]

---

For setting up displacement, you will likely want to use a [subsurf modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) with the ["adaptive" setting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/objects/adaptive_subsurf.html) enabled.

[image]

Here is the example .blend:

[image]

Note: The viewport doesn't properly reload yet, so you have to keep switching between solid and rendered view.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. I was looking for the Displacement option in the Data panel. It was located there in earlier versions of Blender. Thank you.